# How to make a bandana knot in blender?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, curve-modifier, blenderkit

I have started learning blender a month or so ago. I am trying to model a bandana in blender 3.0 and I believe I have done a half-decent job so far, but I have been banging my head for the last three days to work on a neat knot for my bandana but have had no success so far. To be honest, it is nowhere close to looking like a knot, I tried using a curve modifier but with no success,
I am using the famous Tupac bandana knot as a reference point
[image]

Any help or a sample blend file would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe an easy and quick way to do that is by using *Skin modifier*:

1. Add a default circle and select one vertex:

[image]

2. Rip that vertex with V and move up on the Z axis:

[image]

3. Move the vertex below down on the Z axis as well:

[image]

4. Extrude the top vertex 2 times as shown:

[image]

5. Extrude the bottom vertex 2 times as shown:

[image]

6. Select these 2 vertices:

[image]

7. Move them backwards on the Y axis:

[image]

8. Add a *Skin* modifier:

[image]

9. Select all vertices, press CTRL+A and scale down the size:

[image]

10. Add a *Subdivision surface* modifier and select these 2 vertices and scale down on Z axis to bring them closer:

[image]

11. Adjust the vertical thickness of nearby vertices with CTRL+A and Y:

[image]

12. You can subdive between some vertices to add detail:

[image]

[image]

13. You can use proportional editing with CTRL+A and Y to set overall shape:

[image]

14. From this basic shape you could continue to perform further changes on the model:

[image]

I hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a million for this Alberto - it is very nicely explained

Comment: Glad to help! :)